# Finding duplicates in field values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How do I find duplicates in a certain field?

Plus, for every duplicate, I would like to obtain corresponding row value from another field.

I am new to python programming.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  We need more info.  Can you please **[edit]** your question to include details about your data, what kind of duplicates are you looking for?  What are you wanting to do with the corresponding row values?  What have you tried and what happens when you try it?  You mention python - if you're trying to do this in python please also include a snippet of the code you've tried and any error messages you encounter when you run it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Find Identical](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/find-identical.htm) Tool

The tool *reports any records in a feature class or table that have identical values in a list of fields, 
and generates a table listing these identical records. 
If the field Shape is selected, feature geometries are compared.*